# find common data point in multiple sets

Tags: python, optimization, regression

I have multiple sets of data points. For example, set 1 contains 5 data points, set 2 contains 1 data point, set 3 contains 10, etc. I need to select one data point from each set so that distances between these selected points is minimal. Any Python based functions to be used will be very helpful

Comment: i think this is basically a variation on the traveling salesman problem which is NP Hard but has many implementations you could google

Comment: the difference is that in this case you can't go through more than one node in a given set. I have to select one data point from each set, not more than one. I thought there is a way to use some built in functions within a loop. Thanks

Comment: there is no builtin to solve this for you that i know of...

Answer (score 1):

A simple **mixed-integer programming model** can look like:

```
 data:
      dist[i,j] 'distance between points'
      data structure indicating which points are in group g         
 binary variables:
      x[i]    '1 iff point i is selected'
      y[i,j]  '1 iff points i and j are selected'
 objective:
      min sum((i,j) where i<j, dist[i,j]*y[i,j])
 constraints:
      sum(i where i is in group g, x[i]) = 1   for all groups g
      y[i,j] >= x[i] + x[j] - 1                for all i<j
```

The first constraint says: select one point from each group. The second one says: if points i and j are selected then y[i,j]=1. The objective calculates the sum of all distances between selected points (be careful not to double-count distances).

We can optimize the indexing a bit by exploiting y[i,j]=0 if i and j are in the same group.

This is a linear MIP model that can be solved by any MIP solver. Of course, better solvers will solve it faster.

With a random data set of 100 points and 10 groups, it took 27 seconds to find the proven optimal solution using random distances. (This random data set may or may not be much more difficult than real ones).

This model has almost nothing in common with TSP models.

Here is a visualization of a smaller data set (50 points, 5 groups, random coordinates, Euclidean distances):

[image]

Some more experiments on this model are here: http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/10/select-points.html.

Comment: What solver did you use?

Comment: I think this was with Cplex.